# Assembly reflection problem in Release mode

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly, mscorlib

I'm facing some weird behavior trying to get the parent assembly in some logging class (only when it's compiled in **Release** mode).

In **Debug** mode this works like a charm:

```
StackFrame[] frames = new StackTrace().GetFrames();
var assemblies = (from f in frames
                  select f.GetMethod().ReflectedType.Assembly)
                  Distinct()
                  .Last();
```

Example:
**assembly A** => **assembly B** => **method**

when I run the above script in debug mode I get **assembly A** (as expected) but when it runs in release mode I get: **mscorlib** instead.
but the most weird thing is that if a check for the whole assemblies stack **there is not a single reference of assembly A**. how is this possible? what can be happening?

PS: assembly A is a webapp project.

Comment: The method is probably being inlined. Try sticking [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] on it to verify that is what's happening

Comment: Btw you're probably better off calling MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ReflectedType.Assembly which is probably more performant than constructing new StackTrace/Frames only to request the Last one (even if you don't change it, you should remove Distinct. It's just extra overhead and unnecessary iterating especially when you only care about the last one in the collection )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue. I think this problem is related with the compiler behaviour in release mode. I think it has something to be with the method inlining (even when I can't not be sure).

I found this conditions in order to prohibit the JIT from being able to inline a method (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12910766/revisions)):

- Methods that are greater than 32 bytes of IL will not be inlined.
- Virtual functions are not inlined.
- Methods that have complex flow control will not be in-lined. Complex flow control is any flow control other than if/then/else; in this case, switch or while.
- Methods that contain exception-handling blocks are not inlined, though methods that throw exceptions are still candidates for inlining.
- If any of the method's formal arguments are structs, the method will not be inlined.

I tried with all the above recommendations, but the only one that worked for me was to add a parameter (optional) to my method in order to get it greater than 32 bytes.

Hope this helps to anyone!

Answer (score 0):

I've created a sample console application with name of consoleA and a class library with name classB.

It return ConsoleA in both situation. 
I think your problem is that your A application is a web app and when it has run by another service, which in this case is IIS, it return the running service which hosts your app(assembly A).

Comment: Exactly, in a class library project everything works as expected (same in Debug mode). But do you think is it possible to find some workaround for webapp project ?

Comment: @gapin I think that you can use this code to get your executing assembly when running it from service. I always use this code when I run my app as windows service. If it will help, please mark as answered and vote up. Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);